# Run ASP.net c# Web Application Automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, automation

I have a ASP.net web application that checks the status of my servers, it then wraps all this information up and puts it in a email. My Question how do I run this automatically say every day at like 2:00am, or like every 12 Hours?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution is to create a simple MS Windows Service which will do this job.

Comment: +1 This way you can keep all your asp.net code and just call the page from the service.

Comment: Yes, do that. If you want help with scheduling, you could use Quartz.Net at http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

You'd better implement this as a separate process from your ASP.NET application. Phil Haack has summarized the reasons in [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx). A Windows service for example or even a console application using the windows scheduler could work just fine for this task.

Answer (score 2):

You want a scheduler - I recommend [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).

As others have said, your code doesn't have to be in a web app.

If it is, then schedule a job that uses `WebClient` to make a request to your web app.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [WebDriver](http://nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver).

It's intended as a test / qa framework, but there's nothing stopping you from using it in a console application, which you can then run as a Scheduled Task. Note that whatever machine runs the Scheduled Task has to have a browser that WebDriver can fire up.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to create a scheduled task on your server using the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) and setup this job so that it uses internet explorer to visit your webpage.

If you open the task scheduler and create a new task. In the "Run" field put:

> "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE""http://www.yoursite.com/yourpage.aspx"

Then in the "Start in" field put:

> "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer"

Now configure this task to run at 2:00am every day.

Comment: Won't this just open a new Internet Explorer window on the server desktop? It's better to schedule a task that uses [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) instead of Internet Explorer.

Comment: It will visit your web page using internet explorer. I don't know if it opens a window or not but there isn't anything left open once it has finished visiting the web page.